# RowType support in Presto

Tags: presto, trino

Question for those who knows Presto API for plugins.

I implement BigQuery plugin. BigQuery supports `struct` type, which could be represented as `RowType` class in Presto.

`RowType` creates `RowBlockBuilder` in `RowType::createBlockBuilder`, which has `RowBlockBuilder::appendStructure` method, which requires to accept only instance of `AbstractSingleRowBlock` class.

This means that in my implementation of Presto's `RecordCursor` `BigQueryRecordCursor::getObject` method I had to return something that is `AbstractSingleRowBlock` for field which has type `RowType`.

But `AbstractSingleRowBlock` has package private abstract method, which prevents me from implementing this class. The only child `SingleRowBlock` has package private constructor, and there are no factories or builders that could build an instance for me.

How to implement `struct` support in `BigQueryRecordCursor::getObject`?
(reminding: `BigQueryRecordCursor` is a child of `RecordCursor`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assemble the block for the row by calling `beginBlockEntry`, appending the values for each column via `Type.writeXXX` with the column's type and then `closeEntry`. Here's some pseudo-code.

```
BlockBuilder builder = type.createBlockBuilder(..);

builder = builder.beginBlockEntry();
for each column {
    ...

    columnType.writeXXX(builder, ...);
}
builder.closeEntry();

return (Block) type.getObject(builder, 0);
```

However, I suggest you use the columnar APIs, instead (i.e., `ConnectorPageSource` and friends). Take a look at how the Elasticsearch connector implements it:

https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/master/presto-elasticsearch/src/main/java/io/prestosql/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchPageSourceProvider.java
https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/master/presto-elasticsearch/src/main/java/io/prestosql/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchPageSource.java

Here's how it handles Row types:

https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/master/presto-elasticsearch/src/main/java/io/prestosql/elasticsearch/decoders/RowDecoder.java

Also, I suggest you join `#dev` channel on the [Presto Community Slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html), where all the Presto developers hang out.